# В процессе бэкапа возникли ошибки! И можно удалять файлы в var/www/user/data/mod-tmp/

Tags: ispmanager

Здравствуйте.

После резервного копирования. ISPmanager 5 Lite сообщает об ошибке.

Параметры уведомления - backup_warnings ftp_plan_backup.2015-08-01_02-30-02
Описание:

В процессе резервного копирования по плану 'ftp_plan_backup' возникли некритические ошибки

Дополнительная информация

*var/www/tfox/data/mod-tmp/sess_01hnk3utj9b12tq1c5g4tiur67  tar: ./var/www/tfox/data/mod-tmp/sess_01hnk3utj9b12tq1c5g4tiur67: Warning: Cannot open: Permission denied
var/www/tfox/data/mod-tmp/sess_0mismm35l3fp5k13f46nbcqaq0   tar: ./var/www/tfox/data/mod-tmp/sess_0mismm35l3fp5k13f46nbcqaq0: Warning: Cannot open: Permission denied
var/www/tfox/data/mod-tmp/sess_0nij7ln7st8fvjmpa6tenqmn24   tar: ./var/www/tfox/data/mod-tmp/sess_0nij7ln7st8fvjmpa6tenqmn24: Warning: Cannot open: Permission denied
var/www/tfox/data/mod-tmp/sess_0p1jsq90tok7s2sbglme73o4i1   tar: ./var/www/tfox/data/mod-tmp/sess_0p1jsq90tok7s2sbglme73o4i1: Warning: Cannot open: Permission denied
var/www/tfox/data/mod-tmp/sess_0u4k4f753jt6j45l07a8583335   tar: ./var/www/tfox/data/mod-tmp/sess_0u4k4f753jt6j45l07a8583335: Warning: Cannot open: Permission denied*

Хочу заметить. Эти файлы /var/www/tfox/data/mod-tmp/sess_* - существуют.

У меня два вопроса.

**Первый:** Почему возникла данная ошибка?

**Второй:** Можно ли удалять все файлы в директории "/var/www/tfox/data/mod-tmp/" ?
Решит ли это проблему? Не нанесет ли, удаление всех этих файлов, вреда системе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Первый: Почему возникла данная ошибка?

Судя по названиям файлов, ваш скрипт бэкапа работает в директории, в которой хранятся файлы сессий. Сами по себе сессии - *деликатные* данные, поэтому прав на них не должно быть ни у кого, кроме их создателя, с этой точки все нормально. Что не очень нормально - это то, что бэкап считает эти файлы за те, которые нужно архивировать.

> Второй: Можно ли удалять все файлы в директории "/var/www/tfox/data/mod-tmp/" ? Решит ли это проблему? Не нанесет ли, удаление всех этих файлов, вреда системе?

Как я уже написал, это, скорее всего, файлы сессий. В лучшем случае, вы сбросите авторизацию всем пользователям - лучше вообще не трогайте, исключите директорию из бэкапа.
Кстати, забавный факт: ни одной запятой в процитированных вопросах быть не должно.

Comment: "лучше вообще не трогайте, исключите директорию из бэкапа" Как это сделать? В панели ISPmanager такой функции не нашел.

Comment: @Foxtrot я никогда не пользовался всеми этими панелями и не знаю